# jQuery is duplicating <tr> ans <td>'s in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery is somehow creating extra TR's and TD's. I cant seem to get it to work right.

here is the DOM before running script:
[image: DOM]

Here is my script:

```
<script language='javascript'>
          $(document).ready( function(){

            $('[class^=\"odd\"],[class^=\"even\"]').each( function(){

              // add a row after this row
              html = '<tr style=\"display:none\"><td><td/><td  colspan=\"9\"><td/><tr/>';
              $(this).after(html);


            });

          });
    </script>
```

here is the DOM after running script:
[image: DOM after script]

Comment: For starters this is a mess: `<td><td/><td  colspan=\"9\"><td/>`  It's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are not closing your tags correctly. `<tr/>` should be `</tr>` for example. Try this:

```
html = '<tr style="display:none"><td></td><td  colspan="9"></td></tr>';
```

Note that you also don't need to escape the double quotes in that string, as it is encapsulated in single quotes.

Comment: I'll add that this could have been more easily spotted by viewing the source (view-source:example.com in chrome) rather than using the developer tools.  Dev tools will show you how the markup is being rendered rather than how it was generated.  Viewing the source, OP probably would have spotted the problem faster.

Comment: @JosephMarikle: This is client side code. It wouldn't be seen in the source view. Only place to see it is in the JS source, which the OP failed to do.

Comment: @squint Ah, that's right.  Sorry.  I wasn't thinking clearly.